# Does dripping urine break Wudu?

Tags: salat, wudu, taharah, incontinence

Sometimes after you have finished urinating, it may happen that you drip in your pants right after you perform Wudu or before you go for prayer.

**So I wonder if it breaks the Wudu; what about the pants, do we have to change them every single time? And what if you are at school and can't get changed?**

Answer (score 10):

The general rule if you can control urination:

> If you pass urine or drops of urine, you have to make wudoo’ and wash only the parts of the body and clothing (on which the urine has fallen).

If you have no control over these drops:

> If the situation you describe, the occasional emission of a few drops of urine, is beyond your control, then your case is like that of one who is incontinent, so do the following:
>
> 1. Wash the private parts with water.
> 2. Wash the part of your clothes that the urine has gotten onto (there is no need to change your clothes).
> 3. Put a pad or a piece of cotton, or  something similar, over the private parts so that the urine will not spread.
> 4. Do wudoo’ for each prayer, then pray as you are, and pray as much as you like, fard and naafil, with this wudoo’. After doing this,
>      anything else that comes out does not matter. Allaah says
>      (interpretation of the meaning): “So keep your duty to Allaah and fear
>      Him as much as you can…” [al-Taghaabun 64:16]. Do not miss any prayers
>      or delay doing them on time, and your prayer will be valid.
>
>    This is what should be done in the case of incontinence, but if the
>      urine comes out shortly after urinating, then it stops, in this case
>      you can go to the bathroom fifteen minutes before the prayer or the
>      adhaan, for example, then put something (a cloth, etc) to prevent
>      contamination after you do istinjaa’ (cleaning yourself after
>      relieving yourself), do wudoo’ and pray. And Allaah knows best.

Fatwa by: [IslamQA](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/6656/)

Comment: abrupt or loud noises, squatting, or some long time cause my urine begin leaking. after several minutes after that, drops of urine drip out. if i, before that, go to toilet and pee out that small amount of urine, that is in urethra, i can feel well for 10-20 minutes, or until some noises etc, again, and keep my underpants clean. as i know, according to hadithes, both act of peeing and urine dripping breaks tahara for healthy humans. i think act of peeing and that is after wudu some time like 10-30 minutes before prayer, should also be considered not breaking tahara, for ill persons like me.

Comment: edit: that small amount of urine, that is in urethra >and in bladder<

Answer (score 2):

*This applies only for males.*

It doesn't invalidate your waddu if you have done Istibra (explained below) after taharat (washed with water).

Their are 5 types of penal discharges:

1. wadi (liquid discharged after urination, provided it has not come in contact with urine, which can be ensured if istibra was performed)
2. wazi (liquid seen after ejaculation)
3. mazi (moisture discharge by a man during wooing or courtship)
4. semen
5. urine

1, 2 and 3 are deemed pak (clean). 4 and 5 are najs (unclean), the release of which invalidates waddu and anything that comes in contact with it is deemed najs too.

*Wadi:*

It is the liquid that, at times, comes out after urination. If it doesn't come in contact with urine it is clean.

This might be confusing. To remove that confusion we have Istibra. If one performs Istibra after urination and liquid is discharged thereafter it is deemed clean even if one doubts whether it is urine or urine came in contact with it.

*What is Istibra?* Shortest definition could be, "[*'milking'*](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/ate/liverandkidney/202178.html) of the urethra". It ensures that no more urine is left in the urethra. How does one do that:

> There are certain ways of performing Istibra, and the best of them is that after the passing of urine, if the anus also becomes najis it is made Pak first. Thereafter, the part between the anus and the root of penis should be pressed thrice, with the mid dle finger of the left hand. Then the thumb is placed on the penis, and the forefinger below it pressing three times up to the point of circumcision, then the front part of the penis should be jerked three times.

If one doesn't perform Istibra, and liquid is discharged it is deemed unclean. If one doubts whether he did it properly or not, it is deemed clean. And if one, doubts whether he did it or not it is deemed unclean.

**Reference from Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani:**
[Taharat » Istibra](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2124/)

Answer (score 1):

Brother, i don't know whether you really should follow the posted fatwa as the drop of urination does break the state of Wudu and the only way to perform Sala is to redo it. but since you have a urination problem, i would advise to do the following to eliminate this problem forever.

1- try stopping the urination when you are in a full flow, it may be difficult at the beginning but with some exercise you will find it possible. it actually helps the control system of your bladder that cause the dripping even after you think you have finished urinating.
2- avoid consumption of Tea, Coffee, Cigarettes, or anything that contains caffeine, alcohol is also of the cause.

3- avoid going to the toilette for urination for an extra 10-15 minutes to force your bladder to hold the urine. it helps the control system too.

Brother, hope this will solve your problem forever, if you still face the same problem you should really see a specialist urologist. 
Note: there are authentic hadith about breaking of wudu with urination drop. plus another authentic hadith of sahih bukhari said" Prophet SAWW was shown a grave in which bodies were punished and they haven't committed any major sin other than carelessl urination and back stabbing. so please don't just blindly follow some Mullah's fatwa and get to the root of the problem, may Allah purify us all. Ameen