# Whimsy about the status of my wudhu is affecting my salah

Tags: salat, fiqh

Basically I have a problem that as soon as I start doing wudhu I begin to get all types of feeling such as passing wind but mostly that something will release from my private parts. I get very anxious and sometimes shake my leg a little. This problems starts wen I start wudhu and as soon as I say *salam* and finish salah this problem completely goes away. I know this is waswas/whimsy from shaytan.

Before starting salah I wash my private part and underwear, and right before starting salah I check my private part to make sure it is dry and nothing has released. Sometimes even before starting the salah I see some wetness so I start washing all over again. When I eventually start my salah I get very anxious and feeling like something has released. I always end up breaking my salah to check if something has released but sometimes I ignore it if I feel it is nothing. But because this happens everyday I have become used to the many different feelings that occur in my private parts.

*E.g:*

If a certain feelings occurs that I know in the past has occurred with the release of wetness I break the salah to check and do see some wetness on the tip of the penis. If I don't see anything I start salah again but sometimes I see some wetness on the tip and so start wudhu all over again.

How am I meant to say salah in such a case? Are my wuddhu valid?

It takes up most of my day and I cannot even pray on time.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. I would suggest you focus you question more towards the waswas of passing wind than wetness. Because the issue about wetness has already been addressed in the question [Does dripping break Wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955/3487).

Answer (score 2):

In regards to the issue of wetness. As detailed in this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10509) if one performs Istabra after urination and then feels wetness, then neither are they or their clothings deemed unclean/najs nor does it invalidate/break their wuddhu.

If a person doubts too much and is too whimsical/waswasy about whether their wuddu has been broken or not then they should treat it as valid.

Rule #305-306:

> 305. If a person doubts too often about the acts of Wudhu and its conditions, like, about water being Pak, or its not being usurped, he should not pay any heed to such doubt.
>
> 306. If a person doubts whether his Wudhu has become void, he should treat it as valid. But, if he did not perform Istibra (rule no. 73) after urinating, and performed Wudhu, and thereafter some fluid was discharged about which he was not sure whether it was urine or something else, his Wudhu will be void.
>   307. If a person doubts whether he has performed Wudhu or not, he should perform Wudhu.
>
> ([Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2157/))