# What to do if clothes have dried urine on them?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, taharah

I have a problem that I often fear I passed a small amount of urine during my prayer. This happens so often that I tend to store the clothes I fear may have the impurity on them in my room and not wash them until a few days later. Is this permissible, or is the fact that such a long interval passed between the time the urine came out and it being washed that even if I did wash the clothes thoroughly, it is too late as the urine would have already dried from days ago?

Note: please answer this as accurately as possible so that I can put my mind at ease.

Comment: Related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955

Comment: How about washing them?

Answer (score 1):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

According to your words that declared “I often fear…”, so seemingly obsession is counted as a stumbling block for you! Then initially you’d better notice that you should not pay attention a lot if you feel you are involved in an obsession. Beside in case you assume (probably) the clothes has uncleansed, or you doubt in its uncleaning (Nijasah), thus you have not to care it, and it doesn’t considered as Najis (specifically if you are obsession…).
But in regard to that part of your speech which declared “This happens so often that I tend to store the clothes I fear may have the impurity on them in my room and not wash them until a few days later”

So you said “I fear may have impurity on them”, then, it seems you’d better not notice that if it seems to be changed to an obsession for you. Another point is that as a general Islamic rule, praying by a Najis clothes is invalid. On the other hand, you should wash those unclean clothes before you intent to prayer, and also they would be clean in case they are wet due to washing.

---

**Reference:** [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/6342/?ref=sbttl#gsc.tab=0)