# Thinking about sex or talking about sex with someone of the opposite sex and after the liquid comes out

Tags: salat

Is the perso allowed to perform prayer if there has not been any intercourse or perform ghusl then have prayers ..The fact is thinking about having sex but not in that process.Thanks

Comment: See also: "[Does dripping break Wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955/9123)"

Answer (score 3):

AS @hamza-islam said there are at least two or [3 types of liquid](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=A&Id=34363), one of them is semen (maniy) and the others are more or less normal liquids (madiy and wadiy), that come out due to sexual pleasure. The difference between madiy and wadiy is that the later comes out after peeing!

If semen comes out ghusl is fard/farz. And semen comes out during orgasm! 
But if madiy or wadiy comes out one has to wash his private parts and his clothes if one finds them wet of it! And then one can do wudu' as usual for prayer!

See  also [here](http://islamqa.info/en/10540) and in [Arabic](http://islamqa.info/ar/10540)

And Allah knows best!

Comment: well explained.Thats why fuqaha said to take bath after 40 steps you have taken or have taken a nap.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Would it be considered masturbation and sin if a person thinks sexually and madiy or wadiy comes out on just thinking.

Comment: @Student28 depends on a couple of things for example, is the person you think of your wife or husband? Else it would rather mean you are sinning.

Comment: @Medi1Saif And would it be considered masturbation.

Comment: I can't imagine why it should be considered something like that. But note that thinking of a foreign woman or man could be considered a kind of "zina".

Answer (score 1):

yes, there are two types of liquids. one is semen other is just normal liquid,that comes out due to sexual pleasure. so Ghusl is only farz,when Semen comes out (during orgasm) and not ,when just normal liquid comes, due to sexual pleasure