# Do I need ghusl after after leaking from my penis when being affectionate with my wife?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

I'm married. I have noticed that sometimes drops come out of my penis like transparent water when I hug my wife or kiss her. Do I have to take a bath after this or my clothes become unclean?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27827/thinking-about-sex-or-talking-about-sex-with-someone-of-the-opposite-sex-and-aft) what you describe is madhiy المذي and and no you don't need to perform ghusl, but might clean your cloths and wash your private parts and re-do your wudu'.

Note that madhiy is considered as unclean like urine, but it doesn't break the fast (see for example [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/49752)).

The major [difference](https://islamqa.info/en/2458) between many (sperms) and madhiy is that you might not feel madhiy coming out as it might come out without real arousal.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Does the clothes need to be changed, do they become inpure?

Comment: @localhost whether you change them or not is up to you according the majority view madhiy is impure (najis) so the part of the clothes on which there's a trace of it must be cleaned/washed by water or you may change your clothes.

Comment: Thanks, what kind of book will have such information?

Comment: @localhost each fiqh book starts with a chapter on tahrah (purity) of course you could check hadith compilations. But in that case you'd better turn to those books which have a focus on fiqh related hadith such as al-Muwatta'. But evidences hardly are self explanatory therefore I'd start with a fiqh book which is rather easy to read. I know you rather follow the Hanafi school of fiqh, but I could recommend the book of Abu Zayd al-Qayrawani in Maliki fiqh which is among the books listed in [this Meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/list-of-islam-related-books-in-englis

Answer (score 0):

There are four kinds of watery substance which come out of human body. 1) Urine 2) Madhiyy 3) Vadhiy 4) Maniyy. From these, you have to take bath only for the 4th one Maniyy. 
As far as your question is concerned, the drops come out while kissing and hugging your wife are not Maniyy because watery substance that leaves your body while playing with your wife is Madiyy. Madiyy is a Impurity so you have to clean your dress.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary. It called al-madhi it breaks wudu but ghusl is not needed

Comment: This might be true, but would need some elaboration on your site. Explaining "why do you come to the conclusion that this is madhi" and "what are the rulings on madhi" would make this post more usefull.

Answer (score -2):

It is called pre-cum (with the medical term being more complex) and it comes out because you are sexually aroused.

This liquid is supposed to come out during sex to make the head of the penis smooth (as you might have realised how slippery it is)

Using this logic, yes, it does make you unclean and certainly breaks your ablution (wudhu/wazu). It might break the fast as well although I am not certain of this.

PS: if hugging and kissing alone getting you pre-cum you should be consult a doctor.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site.