# Can your fast break because of madhiyy

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Asslamoalaikum to all of my brothers and sisters..
Well my question is that alhamdulilaah I'm a good person overall but one thing i hate the most is i have too much sexual desire and i wanna say while i was fasting i see some sexual images comes in front of my screen while playing games or while using facebook and specially live even she(some women) i see even they are covered but my thoughts are very bad very bad that's why i hate my thought(specially in these matter) so while seeing these once even while fasting madhiyy comes out from my penis. But I didn't masturbate while the things beyond your approach happens (like wet dream while fasting) will not breaks your fast because you can't control them but seeing my these matter i think it's not beyond my approach but it's also very hard to not to think about it. I'm not good in english but i hope you get whatever i said and if you wanna answer this question plz tell me in light English and in detail..
Thanks(sorry for this language)

Comment: This may answer your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32998/do-i-need-ghusl-after-after-leaking-from-my-penis-when-being-affectionate-with-m/33002?r=SearchResults#33002

Comment: Thanks crimson i got my answer

Answer (score -2):

I think that if you are not exposed to the things that make you lust then you will only lust more. You should learn to see images of women without feeling lust. If you make a woman's body normal to you then you wont feel desire. Learn to see a woman's body for just a natural body and not a sexual body.If you are afraid to see a woman's body because of your desire, then that is a sign that you are making a woman's body sexual when it is not intended to be sexual. That is my opinion from my experience. If you are not used to seeing women's bodies, then seeing them might be a trigger for your sexual desires. Do not avoid seeing those images because you want to avoid your desires. Deal with them so you can change them. Train your mind to think about women differently! You can do this!

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question neither do I see how it is relevant from Islamic perspective.