# Discharges and wudu

Tags: taharah

Alsaam alaykum 
I have a question regarding the different discharges that women face. I read several fatwas but none have helped me much.. as some people are not aware of how complex vaginal discharges could be.. its a little embarrassing but necessary as i have constant doubts about my prayers and often have to repeat them to be safe.

So I wake up with secretions over my clothes but never know what to do as everytime its different. What should I do ( ghusl, wudu,..) if:

1) its clear and watery, no smell until it has dried, and when it did, it smelled like urine

2) its more than usual but not that much. Has a slight smell, slightly white

but i remember no wet dreams and no sexual fantasies.

and another note is that I cant diffrenciate between maniy wadhy and madhy and none of my family seems to know anything to help.. please answer with daleel ( evidence) and asap, thank you

Comment: This should be covered in [ejaculation of precum and totally sperm like substance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/ejaculation-of-precum-and-totally-sperm-like-substance).

Answer (score -1):

**Mani**:
Mani (semen) is discharged with force and causes exhaustion and relaxation, it requires ghusl.

**Mazi**:
 Pre-seminal fluid (mazi) is discharged due to foreplay or sexual thoughts and it intensifies lust. It breaks the *wudhu*; one has to wash it from his body and cloth.

**Wadi**:
If fluid is discharged without lust, it is called wadi. If you are not feeling lust and you find spot of any impurity on underwear or pant, so it is wadi, it did not require *ghusl*.

[Mani and Mazi](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/qa/9685)

[Wadi](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Taharah-Purity/10132)

Comment: Wady doesn't come out while sleeping it comes out after peeing and has no smell. While many has among other attributes that of smelling like urine when it gets dry and scholars agree that wet dream doesn't mean that you remember having dreamt but found the trace of many discharge.