# You have to perform ghusal when only 2 or 3 drops of sperm release from your body and didn't touch to your clothes?

Tags: masturbation

Asslam o alaikum to all of my brothers and sisters... Well my question is that while using facebook or games etc when some sexual images appears on your screen and when seeing these images you are about to cum(sorry for these word) and you suddenly go to bathroom but there if 2 or 3 drops of sperm release from your body but didn't touch to your clothes and you wash your private part carefully.. is it necessary to do ghusal even just for 2 or 3 drops of sperm released and even didn't touch to your body??? Sorry for this language but this means alot to me...

Comment: If you only watch what comes out is not sperm and it is called madhy المذي and doesn't require ghusl. But the [tag:masturbation] leads to a different answer.

Comment: Mady? I have searched on google but there is no any thing related to your this answer

Comment: There are enough answers on that on this site. See for example https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48676/13438.

Comment: Brother but what if madhiyy touches to your clothes then you have to do ghusal or not??

Answer (score -1):

yes. that is pre ejaculation and requires full ghusl.

I even little bits of cum... not full cum everywhere... full ghusl or HARAM.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for that? (See [answer]).