# Types of different emissions by a male?

Tags: fiqh, taharah

What are the different types of  emission a male emits from his penis other than urine and semen??How can one differentiate between those emissions based on their physical appearance??especially color??

And what is ruling of obligatory ghusal for each of those emission types.
Please kindly provide references/fatwas with your answers

Comment: These should be covered in [Ejaculation of precum and totally sperm like substance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/ejaculation-of-precum-and-totally-sperm-like-substance/48680#48680)

Answer (score -1):

To make this as brief and simple as I can, these are the rules regarding this issue:

- Every thing comes out of penis (Except semen) is Najis (you need to wash your clothes off it, in case any of it spelled on them.), and they require only wodo.
- Semen is the only non Najis emission, but you need to do a full body ghusal after it, in case the semen came out with pleasure. So in case it came out because of a disease or coldness or any other reasons that is not for pleasure purposes it does not require any ghusal.

Comment: Wrong and without any authentic reference. semen release with any intention makes one Najis and require compulsory bath.

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/156063/ghusl-is-obligatory-if-sperm-comes-out-with-strength-and-desire .This is the reference regarding the semen release with no pleasure.
my point was that semen is not Najis by itself, you can just scratch it off and you are good to go. but of course, you need ghusl if the semen came out with pleasure.