# Doubts about madhiy or maniy

Tags: ghusl

Sometimes when I wake up I find a sticky, white, transparent fluid. I'm not sure whether it's madhiy or maniy but I read that semen can be thin and clear on the Internet.

Also I find this fluid only after I wake up, not when I'm awake/feeling aroused. No matter how aroused I feel when I'm awake I won't find any fluid on my clothes or anything.

So should I do ghusl everytime I wake up and find this or just do istinja and splash water on my clothes?

***Also it would be helpful if someone could submit this question for me in Islamqa.info.***

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Where your doubt comes from, both madhy and many have different attributes. One of the clearest is the odor of maniy.

Comment: Walaykum salam, I never find this fluid when I'm awake only after waking up from sleep

Comment: Do you find it as fluid or dry the strongest attribute of maniy is its odor.

Comment: I find it as odorless fluid.

Comment: Then it shall be madhy if you didn't have a wet dream. See [Ejaculation of precum and totally sperm like substance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/ejaculation-of-precum-and-totally-sperm-like-substance) here you may find the attributes of each liquid.