# Can't tell if maniy or mahiny came out

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I have a question because sometimes I watch bad stuff and then I stopped and whole I was watching I checked my private part and I saw normal mehany came out, it wasn't coming out in a big load and it only came out when I squeezed my penis, when I did that I saw a white thick liquid come out and then it went away on my hand, was that semen? Or because it didn't come out in spurts and I didn't have desire of getting it out, after it came out I felt a little bit tired and it smelt like palm a little bit? Is my fast broken? Other then that when I squeezed my penis only mahiny came out

Comment: what's mahiny or mehany?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. In Arabic and Islam we differ between maniy which is sperms and madhy which comes might be described as pre-cum a distinction was explained in [Ejaculation of precum and totally sperm like substance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/ejaculation-of-precum-and-totally-sperm-like-substance). It is unclear what you mean by mahiny or mehany!