# Watching inappropriate videos during fasting and not sure about the discharge was maniy or madhiu

Tags: sawm, ramadan

When I prayed fajar today I saw a inappropriate dance video a liquid came out but when i woke up there was no stain on my pant does my fast is invalid or not ?
May Allah bless you

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. As for the question whetehr it was maniy or madhy you may refer to [Ejaculation of precum and totally sperm like substance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/ejaculation-of-precum-and-totally-sperm-like-substance) in which they are described and distinguished.