# Urine drops come after urination for 10-15 minutes but some time any time

Tags: practical-islam

I am suffering from a disease in which urine drops come after 5 to 15 minute after urination..... For it i usually flow water on my body after it and change clothes but now The issue is urine comes out any time while offering prayer too...

Please help.....i heard that after sprinkling of water i can oofer prayers.... But i am afraid.... About maqboll namaz..... Will Allah qabool my prayers....

.

I don't know the exact words but also heard that k jo taqleef Allah sy aey or ap Allah sy door ho jao to its Azab (Translation: If Allah gives some hardship to you, and it distances you from him, than its his punishment)..... Is it Azab? :/ please help

Comment: Can you translate the last paragraph into English, so everyone can understand it!

Comment: seems duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-dripping-urine-break-wudu

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid brother, you have heard right that you can pray after sprinkling water, on your pants/shalwar or whatever you wear. And keep praying for your health. We also pray to Allah that he give you complete health. And if you think the drops are getting more and more than consider having some under garment, some special undergarment for this, with advice of a doctor.

> Faatimah bint Abi Hubaysh came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) and said: “O Messenger of Allaah, **I am a woman who
>   suffers from constant non-menstrual bleeding (istihaadah), and I never
>   become pure. Should I give up prayer?” The Messenger of Allaah (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, “No**, rather that is from a
>   vein, and it is not menstruation. When your regular time of
>   menstruation comes, then stop praying, and when that time is over,
>   then **wash the blood off yourself and pray, then do wudoo’ for every
>   prayer** until that time comes.” Bukhaari, 226 - Muslim, 333

So, one wudoo for each prayer is sufficient for you.

> “and has not laid upon you in religion any hardship”
>
> [al-Hajj 22:78]

Last thing you mentioned, it is more like a saying of someone. And it makes sense, if someone is getting distanced from Allah because of any reason, that's not good, and that can be a punishment, or a test. It's not necessarily azaab.

Let me quote a beautiful hadees here,

> The Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) said, **“Amazing is the affair
>   of the believer, verily all of his affair is good and this is not for
>   no one except the believer. If something of good/happiness befalls him
>   he is grateful and that is good for him. If something of harm befalls
>   him he is patient and that is good for him”** (Saheeh Muslim #2999)

So, it's not necessary that it's azaab, hardships and diseases are part of life, it's normal, just be patient and keep praying.

### Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you urinate standing. Change that. If I'm wrong, well, your problem is very common, I used to struggle with it myself.

My hack was like this: urinate normally like there is no problem. When possible do it squatting.
Do wash, put pants on, wait for a  moment or two. Usually ten seconds will do. Do not leave the bathroom just yet.
This is the trick. It tells your body that you are done. If it works, do expect the 'leak'. Wash once again, try to wipe this last drop.

It was really frustrating, I know. I hope that solves your problem. If it doesn't then @Zia 's answer is well written and is for you. Allah knows best that you tried.