# How should a person facing urinary incontinence pray?

Tags: salat, incontinence

I am just a 14 year old boy right now and I have had discovered urinary incontinence since i started offering prayers regularly (10/11 year old), I had these issues before but ignored them as I didn't perform prayers and it didn't affect me. Now what are the rulings for me. Will this break my wudu? How should I cover it, etc. Although I am trying to cure this by doing prescribed exercises but until then what to do

Comment: A specialist doctor may be able to inject filler to prevent urinary incontinence.

Comment: It is said that imam Malik had this problem and therefore stopped going to the mosque due to his respect for the Prophet pbuh, at least this is one explanation why he stopped going to the mosque and following funerals etc. he himself only said that he had a good excuse. But this shouldn't hinder you to go to a mosque, I'm not 100% sure about the ruling details, but you should nevertheless perform wudu' for each prayer and pray as nothing happened.

Comment: seems duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-dripping-urine-break-wudu

Answer (score 1):

If your urinary incontinence is constant, when prayer comes, cover your private area and pray as if it is not coming out. If you are too worried about the urine, then Allah knows that you are not praying with your full mind and heart.

If it only comes out at certain moments, such as every half hour or quarter hour, then pray during those breaks in time even if you miss congregation

Answer (score 1):

Incontinence is analogous to persistent vaginal bleeding, and hence the same method of dealing with it applies to it. A person must perform wudu once for each prayer and their wudu will not be considered to be broken by the incontinence during this time. The madhabs differ on whether it should be once for each prayer time or once for each performance of an obligatory prayer.

> جاءت فاطمة ابنة أبي حبيش إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقالت يا رسول الله إني امرأة أستحاض فلا أطهر، أفأدع الصلاة فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ لا، إنما ذلك عرق، وليس بحيض، فإذا أقبلت حيضتك فدعي الصلاة، وإذا أدبرت فاغسلي عنك الدم ثم صلي ‏"‏‏.‏ قال وقال أبي ‏"‏ ثم توضئي لكل صلاة، حتى يجيء ذلك الوقت ‏"‏‏
>
> Fatima bint Abi Hubaish came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) I get persistent bleeding from the uterus and do not become clean. Shall I give up my prayers?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) replied, "No, because it is from a blood vessel and not the menses. So when your real menses begins give up your prayers and when it has finished wash off the blood (take a bath) and offer your prayers." Hisham (the sub narrator) narrated that his father had also said, (the Prophet (ﷺ) told her): "Perform ablution for every prayer till the time of the next period comes."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:228)</sup>

For details you can see: [Al Fiqh ala Al-Madhahib Al-Arbaah](https://archive.org/details/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah/page/124/mode/2up?view=theater) page 124-128

Answer (score -2):

The rules around *namaz* allow for medical conditions. If it's not possible to attend the mosque due to your condition then it is permitted to do the obligatory prayers at home.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -3):

As per Islamic teachings namaz will be prayed in all circumstances and there is no excuse in it. As for as your disease is concerned Islamic scholars suggest a solution for this issue. You can even go in mosque by  changing your trouser for particular namaz and  fresh wadu.  In this case it is necessary that you should have a new trouser for each namaz if urine drops are continuing. ..

Comment: Evidences supporting your claims would make this answer more helpful. See [answer].