Should I do ghusal if urine drops keep coming out?
Assalamualikum! I want to ask 2 questions.

I have a problem where some urine drops continue to come out for 45 minutes after I pee. When I have to do ghusal, I usually wait for 45 minutes after peeing and then perform ghusal. But sometimes, I see urine drops in very small quantity continue to come out even after 45 minutes of waiting. My question is should i perform ghusal even while these drops keep coming out after 45 minutes or should I pee again and wait for further 45 minutes as doing this once I saw that no drop was coming again and then i performed ghusal.
I usually make ablution for every prayer except magrib. My problem is pee drops sometimes  come randomly and most of times they dont. So is it fine when I offer my magrib prayer with same ablution of asr prayer when i will have some doubts of pee drops but i will not be sure about it and in most cases, my rough observation says drops will not come out. Thank You!


Please ask one question per post. Also we do not give personal advice. Urination does not require ghusl. If urine comes out then it breaks wudu, if you have incontinence then get treatment from a doctor and see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47480/. If you have doubts only then see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40099/
